# How to feed a list of disks to RegionUnion

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, regions

I have a bit of code which creates a list of disks (I'm exploring [Gershgorin circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GershgorinCircleTheorem.html)) based on a matrix `tm`.

```
Gd[tm_]:=Module[{cs,rrow,rcol,drow,dcol,dboth},
cs=Diagonal[tm]; (*diagonal entries*)

rrow=Total[Abs[tm],{2}]-Abs[cs]; 
(*sum absolute values in a row excluding diagonal entry*)
rcol=Total[Abs[tm],{1}]-Abs[cs]; 
(*sum  absolute values in a column excluding diagonal entry*)

drow=MapThread[Disk,{ReIm[cs],rrow}]; 
(*map to disks with centers at the diagonal and radii equal to the sums of rows*)
dcol=MapThread[Disk,{ReIm[cs],rcol}]; 
(*again but for columns*)
dboth=Join[drow,dcol];

regrow=RegionUnion[drow[[1]],drow[[2]]]; 
(*find the union of disks generated from row sums*)
regcol=RegionUnion[dcol[[1]],dcol[[2]]]; 
(*again but for column disks*)

RegionIntersection[regrow,regcol]
(*Find the intersection between the union if row disks and the union of col disks*)
]
```

This works as expected, and I can plot the intersection of the unions. However, if I want to generalize this to an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix, I run into a problem because `RegionUnion` wants entries that are not a list. How can I input the disks without having to manually enter each part of the list of disks, which would require me to alter this bit each time I change the size of the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a compact routine for generating the (row-wise) Gershgorin disks:

```
gerschgorin[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] := Module[{diag, mt},
   mt = mat - DiagonalMatrix[diag = Diagonal[mat]];
   Apply[RegionUnion, MapThread[Disk, {ReIm[diag], Total[Abs[mt], {2}]}]]]
```

Note that I use `Apply[]` on the list of `Disk[]` objects generated. I'll leave the extension to the column-wise case up to you.

Comment: Ah! Perfect.  Apply seems to be one of those things that somehow slipped past me.  Thanks!